# tabindex - - is it widely supported?

Tags: html, tabindex

I'm starting some work on some input fields.

I have a decision to make whether to carry out an action on the input:focus itself, or on a larger parent area focus.

In order to make the parent focusable, I intend to add a `tabindex -1`.

I've looked around and know that this stuff has been around a long time, but before I set off on a particular route, it would be good to know whether this works cross browser.

In terms of browsers I need to support, IE10 up, Chrome, Firefox, and the new "IE6", Android (3.0 upwards).

I'd appreciate any feedback as this is not something I can find out on caniuse and not something I can test widely at this stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no.

The HTML5 specification's [notes on `tabindex`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#sequential-focus-navigation-and-the-tabindex-attribute) state:

> **If the value is a negative integer**
>   The user agent must set the element's tabindex focus flag, but should not allow the element to be reached using sequential focus navigation.

However the HTML401 specification's [notes on `tabindex`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-tabindex) state:

> This attribute specifies the position of the current element in the tabbing order for the current document. **This value must be a number between 0 and 32767.** User agents should ignore leading zeros.

If the browser supports HTML5 or ignores the HTML401 specification's implementation notes you're good to go. I have no idea what you mean by *the new "IE6"*, but the other browsers you mention all implement HTML5.

Comment: The new IE6 - refers to Androids browser being incapable of supporting modern CSS elements well - flexbox 2009 spec being a case in point. Only Opera Mini seems to do worse, by not supporting anything.

Comment: @JohnOhara I see. It's worth noting that `tabindex` has nothing to do with CSS though (your question was originally tagged with CSS but I changed it to HTML). I imagine those browsers probably wouldn't have issues if they conformed to the HTML5 spec (even at a basic level).

Comment: I have just come up against an issue that could be a deal breaker with regard to using the parent for focus. I noticed that a child of the focused parent removes focus from the parent, meaning I would have to apply focus to all the children as well.

Comment: As far as the HTML401 spec goes, it’s safe to say that at this point no browser implementors are going to let a requirement in that spec have any influence over what they implement. (I think that’s actually always been the case for the HTML401; the few requirements that it does clearly state have often never aligned with what’s actually implemented, and the vastness of its lack of clearly stated requirements for most other things is in part what led to the mess of interoperability problems in the platform, and the need for an HTML5 spec to document the real requirements.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's been supported for years.